# Short story regarding accidental creation of a messiah by the actions of a survey team

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, religion

I’m looking for (name/author) of a short story I read some time ago.
The theme is a space survey team ( a couple) arriving on a unexplored world.
The prime directive for these survey teams are to NOT affect the population, but to only observe, undetected.

They observe the primitive population offer up a sacrifice to a pagan god by abandoning one of their infant children in the wilderness.
The couple surreptitiously shelter the infant overnight, allowing it to survive, before replacing it in the sacrificial location.

They then sadly leave the planet. One of the team discovers that his pocket (flashlight/laser pointer?) is missing. He recalls the infant being attracted to it, repeatedly muttering “Not a toy!”
The story springs forward to a future scholar studying the origin of various planetary religions by reading their version of scripture or the bible. The story he is reading relates how
the planet population found the infant still (miraculously) alive the next day and …”*the child waved his hand and lighting did issue forth…*” ( or something similar, because the infant had snatched the penlight/laser and activated it).

....And thus that planet's messiah was created.
Story ends with the researcher pondering aloud….” always some force came and somehow influenced the development of religion on these planets. If only we knew the whole story…”

I'm pretty sure it was not online or magazine - most likely it was in an anthology. Mid 1990 to 2000 would be my guess as to when.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when would you have read this?  Was it online, in a magazine or in an anthology?

Comment: Pretty sure it was NOT online or magazine - most likely anthology. Mid 1990 to 2000 would be my guess as to when. Sorry I can't be more specific....